# Searching Artist and Title From Album table Using Only One textbox in Zend Framework2

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

Please suggest me how can i search Artist and Title From Album table using only one common textbox in Zend Framework2

Answer (score 1):

You create a select statement that has the conditions `title LIKE %search_key% OR artist LIKE %search_key%` .